# Moving values in cells within a table onclick of button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to move cell values within a three by three table. But I am moving one cell at a time with the click of a button. Is this possible with jQuery or JS? I have the following table:

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8][9]
```

and I want to click a button to move right like so:

```
[4][1][2]
[7][5][3]
[8][9][6]
```

and so on..

this is my HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="moveStuff">Move!</button>
```

Comment: can you be more specific about what you want to do on click?

Comment: @TilwinJoy I have been trying to get the button to move the value in cell 1 to cell 2, cell 3 to cell 6, cell 6 to cell 9 and so on in a circular motion with each click of the button. All while cell number 5 remains in the same place. I have found a way to move everything 90 degrees, but I need one cell at a time

Comment: @null after one click, the second table would be like <table>
  `<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so hacky and I don't necessarily advise it, but it should give you a place to start out from.  Basically what you can do is create a function that grabs all the `td`s and based on their index value, rearrange them.  Every time the function is called, it recreates the `cells` variable, meaning it will always start out fresh with the correct index values associated with the correct cells.

**Source:** http://jsfiddle.net/9nfvc/
**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/9nfvc/show

### HTML

```
<table id="rotation">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="moveStuff">Move!</button>
```

### javascript

```
document.getElementById('moveStuff').onclick = (function(){
    var cells = document.getElementById('rotation').getElementsByTagName('td');
    var rows = document.getElementById('rotation').getElementsByTagName('tr');

    rows[2].appendChild(cells[5].parentNode.removeChild(cells[5]));
    rows[1].appendChild(cells[2].parentNode.removeChild(cells[2]));

    rows[1].insertBefore(cells[5].parentNode.removeChild(cells[5]), cells[3]);
    rows[0].insertBefore(cells[2].parentNode.removeChild(cells[2]), cells[0]);
});
```

---

## EDIT

I like this way better.

**Source:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZquQL/
**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZquQL/show

### javascript

```
document.getElementById('moveStuff').onclick = (function(){
    var parent = document.getElementById('rotation');
    var cells = [];
    var rows = parent.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var patern = [3,0,1,6,4,2,7,8,5];

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        while(rows[i].firstChild) {
            var node = rows[i].removeChild(rows[i].firstChild)
            if(node.nodeType === document.ELEMENT_NODE) cells.push(node);
        }
    }

    row = -1;
    for(i in cells) {
        if(i%3 === 0) row++;
        rows[row].appendChild(cells[patern[i]]);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for that! I've been hacking at this for a over a day now and only getting one or two cells moving. I totally see what I was missing from what I was trying to do.